# Jquery foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, foreach

```
$("#<%=ApprovalSelectPanel.ClientID %> input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){

    alert(this.val);

});
```

This isn't returned the value attribute on each checkbox, it's returning `undefined`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ maybe this can help too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context, `this` is the DOM object.

Try this instead:

```
$("#<%=ApprovalSelectPanel.ClientID %> input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){

    alert($(this).val());

});
```

Although, this work have worked as well:

```
    alert(this.value);
```

Comment: Thanks!  Been trying to figure that out for ages

Comment: Or, you can try `alert(this.value)`, if you want to avoid a `$` call.